# Convert UNIX timestamp in jQuery

Tags: jquery, getjson

Well, I fetch timestamp from my table using a php page with getJSON. Here is the structure.

main.php --> using getJSON (abc.php) --> value from my table

Is there any way to convert this UNIX timestamp into this format:

> dd-mm-yyyy at hh:mm am

Comment: What format is it stored in the database? Your PHP script itself can send the string

Comment: do you need the timestamp in the browser ? if no have php do this job

Comment: It is stored using  mysql timestamp function.

Comment: @mikakun well I get several datas in several rows which I fetch using getJason method.

Comment: You have to use the procedure explained on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Answer (score 12):

The Unix timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since 1970 (epoch). You would need to convert that to a date object in JS:

```
var date = new Date(unixTimestamp*1000); // *1000 because of date takes milliseconds
```

Once you have the date object, you can use any of the techniques mentioned in the following post:
[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: not working i got
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'format'

Comment: It's not working because you don't have jquery date format plugin

Comment: to create a unix time stamp from `new Date()`   is   `Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)`

Answer (score 4):

```
var dt=eval(unixtimestamp*1000);
var myDate = new Date(dt);
return(myDate.toLocaleString());
```

this will give an output like:`10/27/2014, 12:58:45 PM`

Answer (score 3):

For converting UNIX timestamp to the given format `dd-mm-yyyy at hh:mm am`; you have to first construct a JavaScript Date object and then use either the native JavaScript Date methods or the date.format jQuery Library.

### Step 1: Constructing Date Object

```
var timestampInMilliSeconds = unixTimeStamp*1000; //as JavaScript uses milliseconds; convert the UNIX timestamp(which is in seconds) to milliseconds.
var date = new Date(timestampInMilliSeconds); //create the date object
```

### Step 2: Converting to the Given Format

**Option #1 - Using native JavaScript Date Methods**

```
var day = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate(); //adding leading 0 if date less than 10 for the required dd format
var month = (date.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1); //adding leading 0 if month less than 10 for mm format. Used less than 9 because javascriptmonths are 0 based.
var year = date.getFullYear(); //full year in yyyy format

var hours = ((date.getHours() % 12 || 12) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getHours() % 12 || 12); //converting 24h to 12h and using 12 instead of 0. also appending 0 if hour less than 10 for the required hh format
var minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes(); //adding 0 if minute less than 10 for the required mm format
var meridiem = (date.getHours() >= 12) ? 'pm' : 'am'; //setting meridiem if hours24 greater than 12

var formattedDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' at ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + meridiem;
```

**Note:** The date shown will be based on the client timezone. If you need UTC based time; use **getUTCDate()**, **getUTCMonth()**, **getUTCFullYear()**, **getUTCHours()**, **getUTCMinutes()** and **getUTCHours()** methods of the JavaScript Date Object instead of the provided.

**Option #2 - Using date.format jQuery Library**

- **Download date.format.js**

  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacwright/date.format/master/date.format.js
- **Include date.format.js in your HTML file**

  `<script src="/script dir/date.format.js"></script> //substitute "script dir" with the directory where date.format.js reside`
- **Format the date object**

  You can use the format string in a similar fashion as in PHP

  `var formattedDate = date.format('d-m-Y \\a\\t h:i a');`

### Examples

**Option #1**

```js
var unixTimeStamp = 983112343;
var timestampInMilliSeconds = unixTimeStamp*1000;
var date = new Date(timestampInMilliSeconds);

var day = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
var month = (date.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
var year = date.getFullYear();

var hours = ((date.getHours() % 12 || 12) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getHours() % 12 || 12);
var minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
var meridiem = (date.getHours() >= 12) ? 'pm' : 'am';

var formattedDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' at ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + meridiem;

alert(formattedDate);
```

**Option #2**

```js
var unixTimeStamp = 983112343;
var timestampInMilliSeconds = unixTimeStamp*1000;
var date = new Date(timestampInMilliSeconds);

var formattedDate = date.format('d-m-Y \\a\\t h:i a');
alert(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacwright/date.format/master/date.format.js"></script>
```

**Note:** There are other libraries like moment.js which too does the stuff similarly.