# convert json callback data to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

can i get help coverting this string to date format.

Here is the JSon name and value

```
notBefore: 1413936000000
notAfter: 1479427199000
```

I believe this needs to be converted to US format date mm/dd/yyyy

The callback string looks like this:

```
response.endpoints[0].details.cert.notBefore
response.endpoints[0].details.cert.notAfter
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786736/convert-unix-timestamp-in-jquery

Yes, try using date function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go ahead and craft up a new [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(notBefore)
```

If your values are indeed strings, you can `parseInt()` them

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jfu1Lwx5/)

If you need a simple example for mm/dd/yyyy format, here is a working fiddle to get you up and running.

```
var notBefore = 1413936000000;
var date = new Date(notBefore);
var formattedDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

### [With Basic Format JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kagm0zsp/)

Comment: the value is within json data so I have to reference it but i get Nan/Nan/Nan


var notbefore = response.endpoints[0].details.cert.notBefore
var date = new Date(notBefore)
var formattedDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear()

Comment: Is it a `typeof` string? As I pointed out in the answer, you may need to `parseInt()` the value first

Comment: per your advice it worked like this: var date = new Date(parseInt(response.endpoints[0].details.cert.notBefore))