# Populate Bootstrap Table with data from json source

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I,m new in working with bootstrap and json files and I came to the following problem:

I've got the following code:

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1 class="text text-success text-center ">Kontoauszug</h1>

  <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-url="/json/data.json">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="auszug.betrag">ID</th>
      <th data-field="auszug.unix">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="auszug.transaktionsart">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

And the json I'm working with has the following structure:

```
{
  "auszug": {
    "1604400036082-3450": {
      "betrag": -367.5,
      "von/an_uuid": "Test1",
      "von/an": "Test1",
      "autorisiert-durch": "SYSTEM",
      "unix": 1604400036,
      "transaktionsart": "Lohnzahlung"
    },
    "1604406781759-8437": {
      "betrag": 85.17,
      "von/an": "Test2",
      "autorisiert-durch": "SYSTEM",
      "unix": 1604406782,
      "transaktionsart": "Überweisung"
    },
    "1604395596115-5983": {
      "betrag": 1226.48,
      "von/an": "Test3",
      "autorisiert-durch": "SYSTEM",
      "unix": 1604395596,
      "transaktionsart": "Überweisung"
    }
  },
  "kontonummer": "DEF05487151498683",
  "kontostand": 44641548.66,
  "success": true
}
```

But when I try to run the code I get "No matching records found".
How do I get the data from a json like this into the table?

Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
I don't know how to exactly get the responseText in here but here's a screenshot of the console.log:
[image: console log responseText]

Comment: could you show your javascript, how you load the json file ?

Comment: I thaught with the bootstrap.table I don't need to write additional javascript? Please correct me if I'm wrong :) I added the script srcs to the snippet.

Comment: no you are right, but are you sure the url is okay? the file is touched?

Comment: i think your structure of json file is not good..i dont see the [  ]

Comment: I think the URL is ok. Is it possible for me to check it in this setup? I mean normally I would consolo.log()... The other thing is I don't whether the data-fields are correct. (I think I need to get a level deeper, don't I?

Comment: I edited the json file a bit cause it would,ve been to long to post and maybe something went missing but the "real" json object is fine

Comment: the problem is the keys : "1604400036082-3450" and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What can be observed is that you don't know the key because it is dynamic. What you can do is, make an ajax call and get the data in a variable. Now you have to flat the response so you can pass the Flat array to Bootstrap table. Instead of using *data-url* attribute you follow the process given in fiddle

I have added a fiddle which you can use as an example. I have also added appropriate comment.

HTML

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="betrag">betrag</th>
      <th data-field="autorisiert-durch">autorisiert-durch</th>
      <th data-field="unix">unix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

your Script should be

```
<script>
var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
  
  // do an ajax call here to get the response. your response should be like responseData
  
  var responseData = {
    "1604400036082-3450": {
        "betrag": -367.5,
        "von/an_uuid": "asdqwe2413",
        "von/an": "Test1",
        "autorisiert-durch": "SYSTEM",
        "unix": 1604400036,
        "transaktionsart": "Überweisung"
        },
    "1604406781759-8437": {
        "betrag": 85.17,
        "von/an": "Test2",
        "autorisiert-durch": "SYSTEM",
        "unix": 1604406782,
        "transaktionsart": "Überweisung"
        },
    };
  
  var data = [];
  
  // Here you have to flat the array
  Object.keys(responseData).forEach(function(key){ 
  
  var value = responseData[key]; 
  data.push(value);
  })
    $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
  })
  
  </script>
```

Let me know if you need ajax version of this code.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8ngoh4y1/

Comment: Would be great if I can get an Ajax Version :)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! I tried to make an Ajax call which cuts the "auszug" out of the json response but I didn't get it. Do you have any advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the response you got after making ajax call? While I post the answer with ajax Json call.

Comment: I edited the json to in my question to be correctly formatted also I attached the screenshot of the console.log. Already thank you so much +1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hwnajc5f/ check this fiddle, this has json call

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the unix timestamp to a real date format? Sorry for bothering you...

Comment: var date = new Date(unixTimestamp*1000); follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786736/convert-unix-timestamp-in-jquery